# Scope of a variable and function name

Tags: c, scope

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int,int);

int sum(int x, int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    printf("%p\n", &x);
    printf("%p\n", &size);
    printf("%p\n", &sum);
    sum(x,size);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    sum(2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
hello.c:11:5: error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
sum(x,size);
~~~^
```

Comment: You really want a variable and a function to have same name?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Why is this a problem?

Comment: And anyway, what do you think you are doing while calling `sum(x, size);`? There is nothing to stop recursion so your program will go looping all day long (at least until it reaches max stack)

Comment: @Eregrith I am just playing with stack frames and trying to learn.

Comment: @KorayTugay Because as the compiler tells you, your variable `sum` is not a function pointer, so you can't do `sum(x, size):`. It *could be* a function pointer however, pointing to another function, and thus calling `sum(x, size);` would call *that* function and not your `sum()` function.

Comment: @KorayTugay And I think the downvotes are because you didn't even read the error message... Take the time to try and help yourself, show people what you've tried and why it didn't help you.

Comment: @Eregrith Well but the problem is here, I can see that sum is a function.. So  the error message confused me. Anyway thanks, I learned it now.

Comment: @KorayTugay May I please ask why did you rollback the edit? It lost the tags and the formatting. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you define two separate identifiers of same name for different entities in the same name space, they might overlap. `C11` standard, chapter §6.2.1 states,

> If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap....

<sup>Refer Footnote: Why in this scenario, both `sum`s are in same name space</sup>

So, once you *re-define* the identifier with some other type,

> ....If so, the scope of one entity (the *inner scope*) will end
>   strictly before the scope of the other entity (the *outer scope*). Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is *hidden* (and not visible) within the inner scope.

That means, essentially, in your case, inside function `sum()`, when you're defining `int sum`, basically you're shadowing the *function* `sum`. After the re-definition, `sum` is an identifier of type `int`, in that *function scope*. Thus, inside the function `sum()`, you cannot make a call to `sum()` as that is an `int` type now.

However, FWIW,  the call to `sum()` in `main()` (or, rather, outside `sum()` itself) should be valid, as at that point, `int sum` will be out of scope.

**Solution:** Change the `int sum` variable name to something else.

<sup>Thanks to **@pmg** for the correction</sup>

EDIT:

As mentioned [in the other answer by @juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30750028/2173917), after changing the *shadowing* variable name, your program will compile and once you run it, you'll face [*infinite recursion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion) due to the *unconditional* call to `sum()` inside `sum()` itself. You need to add some *break* condition to end (`return` from) the recursion.

---

<sup>FootNote:</sup>

<sup>Referring to `C11`, **chapter §6.2.3**, *name spaces*, we can say, there are separate *name spaces* for various categories of identifiers, e.g. 1) label names 2) the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations, 3) the members of structures or unions and 4) all other identifiers.</sup>

<sup>So, in this particular case, the function `sum()` and the `int sum` definition will reside in the same name space,  for the `sum()` function scope</sup>

Comment: Yes, you can have the same identifier for different things ... at different times.

Comment: After redefining `sum` (from `int (*)(int, int)` to `int`) you can't use the previous meaning. The redefinition is ok though.

Comment: It's related to [6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1). *"For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is visible (i.e., can be used) only within a region of program text called its scope. Different entities designated by the same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name spaces."*

Comment: hehe, scope is more important to this question than name spaces. I'd swap the 2 sections of your answer (or maybe delete the name spaces one) *-1 changed to +1*

Comment: @pmg Actually I kept the order intact so that the quote from 6.2.1 regarding the "same namespace" becomes easy to understand.  Can that be allowed?

Comment: It's ok ... it was just a suggestion :)

Comment: @Sourav See e.g. juanchopanza's answer: succint, to the point, and also points out the next problem the OP is about to face. Gopi's answer mentions the scope of an identifier, which is important on a deeper level ad thus that answer is a bit better. Yours is like a judges verdict after a long trial. Scopes can and should be explained without standardese.

Comment: As is, it's basically just Gratuitous Standard Quotes + the last two paragraphs.

Comment: @rubenvb I've tried to make my answer proper, as you suggested. Does it look ok now?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I've re-structured my answer. MOved the not-so-important part as the footnote. Does it make this answer any better?

Answer (score 12):

You changed the meaning of `sum` here:

```
int sum = 0;
```

From now on, in the scope in which it was declared, `sum` is an `int`, and this becomes nonsense:

```
sum(x,size); /* Wat? sum is an int!!! */
```

Don't do that, and your code will compile. Once it compiles, you can worry about stopping the recursion.

Answer (score 6):

The scope matters

1. Function name `sum` here has a global scope.
2. Variable `sum` is local and has local scope.
3. The conflict is because inside `sum()` you call `sum()`. Now inside function `sum()` you have 2 objects of same name and of different type hence the error.

If you had something like

```
int  sum()
{
   int sum = 0;
   sum = 10;
   printf("%d\n",sum);
}
```

Then your code would have been fine. Since variable `sum` is local to function `sum()` and it is the only object within function `sum()` with that name.

Instead of worrying about this better to rename the variable and make sure variable name and function name is different

Answer (score 4):

You need to change `int sum = 0` to `int y = 0`, also your program will break as you dont stop recursion at `sum(x,sum)`

Answer (score 2):

Simply change variable **sum** name inside **sum function** to **total**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int,int);

int sum(int x, int size) {
    int total = 0;
    printf("%p\n", &x);
    printf("%p\n", &size);
    printf("%p\n", &total);
    sum(x,size);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    sum(2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable and function is of same name thats why it is de-referencing function and variable same time thats the cause of error